# How to match list view columns to header?

Tags: android, layout

I am trying to match the widths of column headers and the cells of a list view.
I read that setting the width of both to 0dp should work, but it didn't in my case.

The fragment (a Tab) has this layout.

```
 <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/main"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <!-- Header -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/item1"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Finish Seq"
            android:width="0dp"
            android:height="30dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.25" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/item2"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Start Num"
            android:width="0dp"
            android:height="30dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.25" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/item3"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Clock Time"
            android:width="0dp"
            android:height="30dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"  />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/item4"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Actual Time"
            android:width="0dp"
            android:height="30dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.25" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- List Divider -->
    <View android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />

    <!-- ListView (grid_items) -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ListView android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

It has an android:width of 0dp and with a weight of 0.25 the four are equally distributed.

The layout for the grid of the list view is as follows. (I've tried other combinations). In a file called grid_item_summary.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/item1"
        android:text="row_id"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:width="0dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/item2"
        android:text="col_1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:width="0dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/item3"
        android:text="col_2"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:width="0dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/item4"
        android:text="col_3"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:width="0dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I know what the columns will hold (one or two digit numbers and times hh:mm:ss) so it works if I size the columns (header and grid) accordingly. But that can leave space to the right depending on the screen size.
The code to populate the grid (SimpleAdapter, etc.) works when I have absolute widths.
With 0dp there's nothing. Turning on show layout bounds reveals no visible fields.

[image: Screen Capture]

Have since tried android:layout_height="wrap_content" for the TextViews in the grid layout.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? Can You post the solution?

Comment: I don't think I solved it. I have done a major rewrite since then.
I'll take a look at what I ended up doing.

Comment: Ok. for time being I'm giving columns & header same fixed width.

Answer (score 1):

In grid_item_summary.xml
Try changing below,

android:layout_width="0dp"
instead of
android:layout_width="wrap_content"

Hope this solve your problem

Comment: That didn't change anything.
With layout bounds turned on I do see a faint blue "corner" for every row. Despite height being wrap to content and looking good in design view, they are very tall. Very far apart vertically.

Comment: I removed android:width="0dp" (maybe you implied that too) and the rows are visible, good height. But the 0.25 weight is not being honoured. The cells are only as wide as they need to be for the content.